# CSS3 image rotator

Tags: html, css

So I'm making a preloader animation which will be a 4 divs with background images crossfading. I'm wanting them nicely crossfaded at 0.6 seconds each but I'm having no luck. They keep overlapping each other too much and it's just a mess. I feel I just need the right percentage or something.

```
.start_loader .iconfader {
    position:absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-100px;
    margin-top:-100px;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}

#load-icon1 {
    background: url(http://mydomain.com/loader-01.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
#load-icon2 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;
    background: url(http://mydomain.com/loader-02.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
#load-icon3 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;
    background: url(http://mydomain.com/loader-03.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}
#load-icon4 {
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;
    background: url(http://mydomain.com/loader-03.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    25% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@keyframes fade {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)**, it'll help us see a example an sort it out without recreating images and html. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this on Codepen. Check this.

No need 4 divs for this. we can do this on single div with CSS3

http://cdpn.io/rFpmx

**CODE**

```
<div class="loader anim-1"></div>
<div class="loader anim-2"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.loader {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
.loader:after {
  content: "";
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
.loader.anim-1:after {
  -webkit-animation: fader 2.4s linear infinite;
}
.loader.anim-2:after {
  -webkit-animation: fader2 2.4s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fader {
  0%, 20%, 100% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/3/000/01f/210/0fedb27.jpg);
  }

  25%, 45% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/4/005/025/0d0/3ec916f.jpg);
  }

  50%, 70% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/4/000/143/350/1ca561e.jpg);
  }

  75%, 95% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/8/000/2cb/256/2f5ed8e.jpg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fader2 {
  0%, 100% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/3/000/01f/210/0fedb27.jpg);
  }

  25% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/4/005/025/0d0/3ec916f.jpg);
  }

  50% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/4/000/143/350/1ca561e.jpg);
  }

  75% {
    background-image: url(http://m.c.lnkd.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/8/000/2cb/256/2f5ed8e.jpg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I like how the top one looks. Will it work with transparent png images? What Each image is a different shape but all are 200px x 200px. Also is there a way you can post the css code you did?

Comment: YES I ADD THE CODE PLEASE CHECK THAT